# How to make Pytest take screenshots continuously while running tests?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'd like pytest to take screenshots at specified intervals of time while running tests. It's like I want to force the webdriver to make these two operations concurrently.

```
from pytest import fixture


@fixture(scope="function")
def drv(app_config):
    options = app_config.browser[0]
    service = app_config.browser[1]
    drv = browser(options=options, service=service)

    yield drv

@fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def recorder(drv):
    while True:
        drv.save_screenshot(f"./recordings/{str(time())}.png")
```

At the moment. The setup creates a webdriver and then bogs down to take screenshots indefinitely.

I want the webdriver to take screenshots until the driver closes WHILE doing other operations like opening the browser, finding and clicking elements etc.

Answer (score 1):

Pytest is a testing framework and doesn't have any context of what happens in your browser. You'll need to either send the webdriver object to the method in a separate thread and loop till the webdriver is not destroyed or implement the behaviour in your driver.

There are two ways in which you can achieve this :

1. You can use the EventFiringWebDriver that comes with the selenium webdriver. You can basically tell selenium to print something before/after navigation.

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver, AbstractEventListener

   class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
       def before_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
           print("Before navigate to %s" % url)
       def after_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
           print("After navigate to %s" % url)

   driver = Firefox()
   ef_driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver, MyListener())
   ef_driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/")
   ```

   There are tones of event that can be used, you can refer to this [source](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/abstract_event_listener.html#AbstractEventListener)
2. Use the Decorator pattern and decorate the webdriver to have the methods  takes the screenshot for your particular action after a given interval.